# Is there any software except SR 3D Builder with the ability to simulate the interaction of gears that doesn't require scripting?

Tags: technic, ldd, gears

I'm aware that one can do that in LDCad but with scripting.

Should I invest my time in learning SR 3D Builder or is there any other option? It's just not a very intuitive software for me but I might still have to get used to it.

LDD is great, if only it had the ability to simulate the interaction of gears...

Comment: Please be aware that SR 3D Builder is no longer updated software. Keep that in mind if you want to invest time into something that might not be suitable at some point due to being obsolete. LDCad on the other side is actively developed.

Comment: Thanks, that's very valuable info.

Regarding LDCad, do you use scripting to create simulations there? Do you have some idea how hard would it be to learn scripting in LDCad to create realistic simulations for machines & mechanism LEGO models for someone with experience in C#?